# ¿Como puedo validar que un INPUT TEXT no acepte caracteres especiales pero que tambien me acepte el espacio? ?!))$&.'!"@&

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Necesito que me deje validar el espacio tambien

```js
function check(e) {
    tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    //Tecla de retroceso para borrar, siempre la permite
    if (tecla == 8) {
        return true;
    }

    // Patron de entrada, en este caso solo acepta numeros y letras
    patron = /[A-Za-z0-9]/;
    tecla_final = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
    return patron.test(tecla_final);
}
```

Comment: Añade el espacio dentro del grupo de búsqueda. `[A-Za-z0-9 ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la siguiente expresión regular.

patron = /^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$/g;